# How to display the name taking from email in Kotlin. Where as I'm currently using Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I need to display the name whenever a user logs in with email. Currently Registration has been done using firebase.
The users data (Email and Password) has been saved in Firebase Database.

Registration and Login page have been developed. looking for response to display the name as "Welcome User"

Example:

- Email : User1@gmail.com
- Password : 123456

I need to display "Welcome User1" on my screen.

Example 2:

- Email : user2.check@gmail.com
- Password : 123456
  I'm open to displaying either or both of the names which are present before "@".

**My Login Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var signUp: TextView
    private lateinit var username: EditText
    private lateinit var password: EditText
    private lateinit var btnLogin: Button
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        signUp = findViewById(R.id.signUp)
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.ln)
        username = findViewById(R.id.usn)
        password = findViewById(R.id.pwd)

        // initialising Firebase auth object
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


        btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            login()

        }

        signUp.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Registration::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun login() {
        val userName = username.text.toString()
        val pass = password.text.toString()

        if (userName.isNotEmpty() && pass.isNotEmpty()) {

            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userName, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this) {
                if (it.isSuccessful) {
                    val intent = Intent(this, Dashboard::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully LoggedIn", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else Toast.makeText(this, "Log In failed ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Registration Activity**

```
class Registration : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var userName: EditText
    private lateinit var confirmPassword: EditText
    private lateinit var password: EditText
    private lateinit var register: Button
    private lateinit var login: TextView
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration)

        userName = findViewById(R.id.usn)
        confirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.etSConfPassword)
        password = findViewById(R.id.etSPassword)
        register = findViewById(R.id.register)
        login = findViewById(R.id.tvRedirectLogin)
        auth = Firebase.auth

        register.setOnClickListener {
            registerUser()
        }

        login.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private fun registerUser() {
        val usn = userName.text.toString()
        val pass = password.text.toString()
        val confirmPassword = confirmPassword.text.toString()

        if (usn.isBlank() || pass.isBlank() || confirmPassword.isBlank()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "User Name and Password can't be blank", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return
        }

        if (pass != confirmPassword) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password and Confirm Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
            return
        }
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usn, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this) {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                finish()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Registration Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile)

First you need to store the full user email in a variable

```
val userEmail = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser.email
```

Once you have the user's email, you can use `.substringBefore()`

```
val email = userEmail.substringBefore("@")
```

Kotlin Playground:

[image]

Comment: Thanks ItzDavi, it worked and i'm able to capture the data

Comment: You welcome! If it solved your problem please, mark this as the accepted answer. @Akshay